# Matchsticks: Fix the Equation

Tags: visual, lateral-thinking, matches

Here's a simple puzzle I just created:

> Move just one matchstick to fix the next equation:
>
> [image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First move a matchstick like so

> [image]

Then observe from the other direction

> [image]

Giving

> **LI - L = I**
>  a correct equation in Roman numerals.

Comment: Amazing! You were really fast! Just waiting to accept the answer! :)

Comment: Yes! Thank you, I've spent some time on it, but can't figure it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively you can

> move the minus sign match and place it next to the equality sign, turning it into identity: 17 ≡ 17 (seventeen is identical to seventeen).

Comment: That's a good answer. The the spacing between the numbers on the picture makes it not a perfect one :) Good thinking though.

Comment: Another way to do the same thing is to use the minus matchstick to add a cross to a 7 so it just says 17=17 but with two different styles of 7

Comment: @ToddWilcox You could also use that calculator-style 7 with the upper-left vertical line filled in (so it's like a serif).

Answer (score 5):

Required Equation will be like this:

Attempt 1:

> $1-1=0$

Attempt 2:

> If 17 can not be 0 then I guess we just need to remove hyphen sign and put it aside, so it will become 17=17

Attempt 3: (though answer is already given and accepted. I am trying another way)

> If we move horizontal line of 7 and put it diagonal onto equal sign then the equation will be like: 1 - 1 ≠ 17

Comment: Good lateral thinking! You simply don't care about the spacing! Eh eh... However the "perfect" answer was already been discovered.

Answer (score 5):

> Move the stick to form 17>=17[image: 17>=17]

Answer (score 4):

We could also put one matchstick onto another matchstick so it covers it completely, making $17=17$.